# Hand me down computer What to do about no password for virgin?

Tags: updates, password, partial-upgrade

I just got this computer and it has Ubuntu 12.04 LTS on it. I don't know the first thing about this system. I've always wanted to move over to Linux just never had the time. I can only log in as  Guest and I don't have a password for the other account. It looks like the system was refreshed back to new status. There is no history and it says there are 700 updates. Is it better to wipe out the hard drive and reinstall fresh, or is there a work around for getting the password. I can't even access some of the system information without the password. I feel like a virgin on prom night. Any help would be great. I really want to stay with Linux. Thanks.

Comment: You can [reset the password](http://askubuntu.com/questions/24006/how-do-i-reset-a-lost-administrative-password), but I think you might as well just install afresh

Comment: Ok, thanks. Should I stay with Ubuntu or switch to one of the other ones?

Comment: Asking on an Ubuntu site is likely to get you the answer to stick with Ubuntu, but it really is one of the best choices for someone getting to know Linux.

Comment: I just figured I would at least get some kind of feel for what was better. Of course everybody had their own idea what's best. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 3):

As for a computer who was set up by another person, you should for the sake of being secure freshly install it yourself.

Just go to https://www.ubuntu.com/download and get an image of your preferred Ubuntu version.
**Note: 12.04 will be EOL (which means end of lifetime) in a few months, so you might want to consider at least 14.04 or higher depending on your system.**

Then use the `Startup Disk Creator` to burn it on an USB-drive and start from it to do a fresh installation.
Or if you prefer to use a DVD then have a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BurningIsoHowto

Comment: Yeah that's what I was thinking. Thanks for your help and links. When I put a blank dvd in does it format right from the start? It sounded like it was but I got nothing on the screen to tell me what was doing what.

Comment: Added a link about how to burn a DVD to my answer.